# Use toggleClass to only toggle one item/div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CODEPEN HERE: https://codepen.io/shannon-creativeasset/pen/mvYPNp

I'm trying to get a flip card effect when you click on the button. However, when you try to flip one box, it flips all of them.

Does anyone know a fix to this but still using the button to flip?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var s_round = '.s_round';

 $(s_round).hover(function() {
  $('.b_round').toggleClass('b_round_hover');
  return false;
 });

 //$('.flip_box').click(function() {
   //$(this).toggleClass('flipped');
 //});

 $(s_round).click(function() {
   $('.flip_box').toggleClass('flipped');
   $('.s_round').addClass('s_round_click');
   $('.s_arrow').toggleClass('s_arrow_rotate');
   $('.b_round').toggleClass('b_round_back_hover');
   return false;
 });

 $(s_round).on('transitionend', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('s_round_click');
  $(this).addClass('s_round_back');
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `this` `parent` and `children`, you must access the clicked element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var s_round = '.s_round';

 $(s_round).hover(function() {
  $('.b_round').toggleClass('b_round_hover');
  return false;
 });
  
 //$('.flip_box').click(function() {
   //$(this).toggleClass('flipped');
 //});
  
 $(s_round).click(function() {
   $(this).parent().parent().children(".flip_box").toggleClass('flipped');
   $(this).addClass('s_round_click');
   $(this).children(".s_arrow").toggleClass('s_arrow_rotate');
   $(this).parent().children(".s_round").toggleClass('b_round_back_hover');
   return false;
 });

 $(s_round).on('transitionend', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('s_round_click');
  $(this).addClass('s_round_back');
  return false;
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  margin-top: 70px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

h1,
p,
a,
span {
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

h1,
p,
a {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.b_button {
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.container,
.flip-box,
.front,
.back {
  width: 380px;
  height: 350px;
}

.container,
.flip_box {
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container {
  -moz-transform: perspective(1200px);
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.flip_box {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  background: 
    rgba(32,32,32,0.83)
    url(https://viewtecsigns.ca-staging.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Railway-Datum-Plate-viewtec-signs-railways-signs-nottingham.jpg);
}

.f_title {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.f_subline {
  padding-top: 205px;
  color: #B1D4E8;
}

.f_headline {
  line-height: 23px;
}

.back {
  background-color: #D21849;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.b_headline {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.b_text {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.b_button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 36px;
  bottom: 38px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #C30C3D;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.b_button:hover {
  background-color: #E30143;
}

.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.r_wrap {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 38px;
}

.b_round,
.s_round {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #D21849;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.b_round {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #D21849;
}

.b_round_hover {
  transform: scale(1.37);
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.b_round_back_hover {
  background-color: #F60044;
}

.s_round_click {
  transform: scale(1.7);
}

.s_round_back {
  background-color: #C30C3D;
}

.s_arrow {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background-image: url('https://viewtecsigns.ca-staging.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/white-arrow-transparent-png-22.png');
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.35s linear;
}

.s_arrow_click {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>

  <div class='flip_box'>

    <div class='front'>
      <p class='f_title'>Signage Solutions</p>
      <p class='f_subline'>Lineside & Railway</p>
      <h1 class='f_headline' style="font-size: 20px;">Station Platform Signs</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class='back'>
      <h1 class='b_headline'>Station Platform Signs</h1>
      <p class='b_text'>Traffic management is critical for safely<br> directing vehicles through roadworks on our<br> busy road and motorway network.<br> Viewtec are specialists in the manufacture<br> and supply of traffic management signs<br>covering the whole of the UK.</p>
      <button class='b_button'><span>Discover Solution</span></button>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class='r_wrap'>

    <div class='b_round'></div>
    <div class='s_round'>
      <div class='s_arrow'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

    <div class='container'>

  <div class='flip_box'>

    <div class='front'>
      <p class='f_title'>Signage Solutions</p>
      <p class='f_subline'>Lineside & Railway</p>
      <h1 class='f_headline' style="font-size: 20px;">Station Platform Signs</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class='back'>
      <h1 class='b_headline'>Station Platform Signs</h1>
      <p class='b_text'>Traffic management is critical for safely<br> directing vehicles through roadworks on our<br> busy road and motorway network.<br> Viewtec are specialists in the manufacture<br> and supply of traffic management signs<br>covering the whole of the UK.</p>
      <button class='b_button'><span>Discover Solution</span></button>
    </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class='r_wrap'>

    <div class='b_round'></div>
    <div class='s_round'>
      <div class='s_arrow'></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you add the `.click` function to all elements with the class `s_round`.

You can solve this by giving them an individual class, or better, assign them an id.

For example rename `s_round` to `s_round1` and `s_round2` and make a seperate function for each of them.

The cleanest way to solve this would be to use `this` (https://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/) tho.